# Getting value error and don't understand why

Tags: python, string

I can't quite figure out why I'm getting a value error with the below python code.  I'm aware (for the most part) that it's telling me that it's not finding the value within whatever I'm passing it, but I don't really understand why.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from math import gcd

lower = ascii_lowercase

def affineDecrypt(ciphertext, a, b):

    if gcd(a, 26) != 1:
        raise ValueError('a and 26 are not coprime. Please try again.')

    msg = ''.join(x for x in ciphertext if x.isalnum())
    out = ''
    n = 1
    count = 1

    while True:
        if a*n > 26*count:
            if a*n == (26*count) + 1:
                break
            count += 1
        n += 1

    for char in msg:
        if char.isalpha():
            d = int((n*(lower.index(char) - b)) % 26)
            out += lower[d]

        else:
            out += char

    return out
```

```
Error:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-8c8ae6f51f75> in <module>
----> 1 affineDecrypt('UBBAHK CAPJKX',17,20)

<ipython-input-31-215f26339a67> in affineDecrypt(ciphertext, a, b)
     23     for char in msg:
     24         if char.isalpha():
---> 25             d = int((n*(lower.index(char) - b)) % 26)
     26             out += lower[d]
     27 

ValueError: substring not found
```

Help?

Comment: What are your inputs?

Comment: affineDecrypt('UBBAHK CAPJKX',17,20)

Comment: `isalnum()` does not imply a character will exist in `ascii_lowercase` ... maybe you intended to lowercase each char in `msg`?

Comment: No related but instead of ```lower = ascii_lowercase``` just do ```from string import ascii_lowercase as lower``` or avoid it all together and just use ```ascii_lowercase``` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for an index of uppercase 'U' in `lower` variable, which is an all lowercase string.

Coerce `char` to lowercase:

```
d = int((n*(lower.index(char.lower()) - b)) % 26)
```

and you should be fine.

Also, change the `lower` variable name to something else. there's a string method with that name.

Comment: This worked for me.  I also updated the variables to be less confusing.  Thanks for the input!